# Does model.compile() go inside MirroredStrategy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, multi-gpu

I have a network for transfer learning and want to train on two GPUs. I have just trained on one up to this point and am looking for ways to speed things up. I am getting conflicting answers about how to use it most efficiently.

```
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=["/gpu:0", "/gpu:1"])
with strategy.scope():
    base_model = MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(200,200,3))
    x = base_model.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name="class_pool")(x)
    x = Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="class_dense1")(x)
    types = Dense(20,activation='softmax', name='Class')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[types])
```

Then I set trainable layers:

```
for layer in model.layers[:160]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[135:]:
    layer.trainable=True
```

Then I compile

```
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=.0000001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='accuracy')
```

Should everything be nested inside`strategy.scope()`?

This [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras#create_the_model) shows `compile` within but this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#using_tfdistributestrategy_with_tfkerasmodelfit) shows it is outside.
Thefirst one shows it outside

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))])

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
```

but says this right after

> In this example we used MirroredStrategy so we can run this on a machine with multiple GPUs. strategy.scope() indicates to Keras which strategy to use to distribute the training. Creating models/optimizers/metrics inside this scope allows us to create distributed variables instead of regular variables. Once this is set up, you can fit your model like you would normally. MirroredStrategy takes care of replicating the model's training on the available GPUs, aggregating gradients, and more.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where it goes because under the hood, `model.compile()` would create the optimizer,loss and accuracy metric variables under the strategy scope in use. Then you can call `model.fit` which would also schedule a training loop under the same strategy scope.

I would suggest further searching as my answer does not have any experimental basis to it. It's just what I think.